# Can cabal find matching versions for given set of packages?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm in situation where I cannot install new package without reinstalling others (my distribution comes without sandbox).

Is it possible to determine which version of each package I should use so that there will be no conflicts with new one included?

How can I encode this set to create new cabal sandbox?

Comment: it's very hard to tell because you gave no details but I would just start from scratch, only install the plattform (or only ghc/cabal/alex/happy) and then go `cabal sandbox` all the way (meaning just do `cabal install cabal-install` and from there on try to use only sandboxes) - BTW you can download the packages you need, inspect the `.cabal` files yourself for dependencies and try to sort it out but I doubt that you do a better job than `cabal install` (that was created to do just that)

Comment: In other words, don't use your distribution's version of cabal if it is out-dated.  Just install the latest cabal to get sandbox support.

Answer (score 2):

`cabal install --dry-run --avoid-reinstalls` should give you some output that indicates the installation plan for a particular package, or fail if it cannot avoid reinstalls due to dependencies.

However, sandboxes are really quite helpful.  Independent of how you bootstrap your cabal installation (tarballs, distribution packages, etc.), you should probably add ~/.cabal/bin early in your path and then `cabal install cabal-install`.  This should only fail if the latest version of cabal doesn't work on your version of ghc / base.